# Install directory from deployment projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory, deployment-project

I'm developing an application and I'm going to deploy it with the help of a deployment project (which is gonna create an installer).

At one step in the installer, it will allow the user to change the installation folder for the application.

I need to know what this folder is because there will be some files saved there that I need to use from another DLL file. How can I programmatically get this installation folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class.  Add a new class derived from this class to your application's project.  Don't forget to apply the RunInstaller attribute.

In your deployment project, add a Custom Action for Install and Commit.  For the CustomActionData property for the Install custom action, enter `/Targetdir="[TARGETDIR]\"`.

In your Installer class that you created in the application's project, override the Install method, and in this method you can get the installation directory like this:

```
string targetDir = Context.Parameters[ "TargetDir" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really simple setup, where the current assembly is installed in the main TARGETDIR, then you can use:

```
String targetDir = new System.IO.FileInfo(GetType().Assembly.Location).DirectoryName;
```