# C# uninstall event

Tags: c#

Is it possible to catch the uninstall event and execute some code when the program starts uninstalling?

program is installed by autoinstall. i already try to use this

```
public override void Uninstall(
 IDictionary savedState
)
```

but it said that method can not be overriden becouse it does not exist.

Comment: When what program is uninstalling? With what uninstaller?

Comment: c# windows application with add/remove programs uninstall

Comment: You need to be way more specific. Is the c# program that should receive the event the same as the program being uninstalled? How have you created the uninstaller? Is your program running when the program is uninstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) listener for deletion of instances of [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4acy5e2.aspx), you would need to use `Win32_Product` and `__InstanceDeletionEvent` though.

This applies to software installed using Windows Installer, at least.  For others, you may have to brute force the registry settings or the like.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about Setup projects in Visual Studio then look at this thread: [Install directory from deployment projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865572/install-directory-from-deployment-projects/3866005#3866005).  You can execute code on the install and uninstall using the [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class.