# Execute code before uninstall of a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have created a WPF Click-Once application which is running perfectly.

Now, I want to execute some code before this application gets uninstalled. Basically I want to inform the server that an application from this particular machine is uninstalled.

But I didn't find any feasible way to achieve this.

Could you please provide your thought on this? How to achieve this?

I am not sure whether it is possible or not. If not then is there any alternate way to do so like by creating `setup project`.

Comment: My guess is ClickOnce apps models [Code Access Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security). Thus, it won't be able to do so.

Comment: Is it possible if I create setup project ? If so then how ?

Comment: I'm sorry, as I haven't done anything like this yet, I won't be able to help you. But you can check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249369/c-sharp-uninstall-event) out.